# Foundation - Sticky not working on small screens

Tags: sticky, zurb-foundation-6

I've got a sticky nav, which is working on all sizes, and I'd like to have a div stick under the nav on scrolling (it'll be filters to filter posts on the page).

http://mindtools.io/rob-test-mobile/

So the "This is STICKY" h1 is sticking on medium and large, but not on small. Is there something obvious I'm missing here? Why is this not sticking on small sizes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

by default data-sticky is set from medium up. add data-sticky-on="small" to get it working on small devices as well
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html#js-options

Comment: `data-sticky-on` still does not work in Foundation 6.5.3. Issue #9892: [Sticky component doesn't honor data-sticky-on attribute #9892](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/9892).

Comment: It's super frustrating how hidden this is in the documentation.

Comment: Glad I found this, thanks for the info. Just spent an hour trying to work out what was going on. They really need to make this more obvious in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I had

```
data-top-anchor="1" data-options="marginTop:0;stickyOn: small;"
```

in my sticky element, but it wasn't sticking on small, but swapping in :

```
data-options="anchor: page; marginTop: 0; stickyOn: small;"
```

got it working